# Arduino command line vs. Arduino builder

Tags: programming, build, command-line

I'm working on adding my Arduino to continuous integration and I came across two different possible ways of doing this, [Arduino command line](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc), and [arduino-builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder).  Can someone explain why the arduino-builder tool exists separately from calling Arduino from the command line?  And what are the advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: ...and http://platformio.org/#!/frameworks

Comment: I've discovered one downside of calling arduino_debug (on windows) from the command line.  It generates graphical pop-ups for errors instead of command line messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Arduino IDE command line predates arduino-builder and was made available when the source pre-processing and compiling was implemented by a Java class (deeply) embedded in the IDE.

The current IDE uses arduino-builder behind the scenes to process and compile the code so if you use arduino-builder you avoid having to load the whole Java IDE. Try it out it does some pretty cool stuff

Answer (score 1):

I've written [a new option for Arduino CI/unit testing](https://github.com/ifreecarve/arduino_ci) and put together [a decent size writeup about it as an answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161903/2063546).

I ended up using the Arduino command line instead of arduino-builder, because it worked better cross-platform for me.  It assumes a graphical display though, even if you just use the CLI features.  In the case of Travis CI, I needed to spin up a fake X display to handle the initial splash screen and other graphical error messages.  (Fortunately, you can tell based on how long a command takes to complete whether it's waiting for you to acknowledge a graphical error message.)

Some examples of how to enable CI on your own project:

- The [DoSomething example library](https://github.com/ifreecarve/arduino_ci/tree/master/SampleProjects/DoSomething) shown above, used to test arduino_ci itself
- A practical example, [testing a Queue implementation](https://github.com/sdesalas/Arduino-Queue.h/pull/1/files)
- A complex example, simulating a library that controls an interactive device over a SoftwareSerial connection as part of the [Adafruit FONA library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_FONA/pull/91/files)